# How i get back to old scene in SpriteKit?

Tags: objective-c, swift, transition, scene

How can I go to old scene in SpriteKit ( in Swift ) ? I am in scene1 , i paused it and i move to scene 2 and I want to get back to scene1 and i to resume it . I don't want to recreate it again .
Thanks.

EDIT :

So , I tried this :
In secondScene class i put a oldScene SKScene property and a computed setOldScene property:

```
class SecondScene: SKScene {

var oldScene:SKScene?
var setOldScene:SKScene? {
                          get { return oldScene }
                          set { oldScene = newValue }
                         }

init(size: CGSize) {

    super.init(size: size)

    /* Setup my scene here */

}}
```

And then , in FirstScene class ( where i have ONE moving ball ) , in touchBegan method i have this

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    for touch: AnyObject in touches {

        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        if(self.view.scene.paused) {
            self.view.scene.paused = false
        }
        else {
            self.view.scene.paused = true
        }

        var secondScene = SecondScene(size: self.frame.size)
        secondScene.setOldScene = self.scene

        if !transition { self.view.presentScene(secondScene, transition: SKTransition.doorsOpenHorizontalWithDuration(2)) ; transition = true }



    }
}
```

But , when i call `self.view.presentScene(oldScene)` in SecondScene class i move yo first class and i have TWO balls that moving :-??

I can't use class variable , Xcode not suport yet .

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by having a public property on the second scene. 
And then using that to present the first scene.

So in the First Scene, when you want to show the second scene....

```
if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "SecondScene") as! SecondScene?
{
    scene.parentScene = self
    self.view?.presentScene(scene)
}
```

This following code is in the SecondScene.
When ready to return to the first scene, just call the method showPreviousScene()...

```
public var parentScene: SKScene? = nil

private func showPreviousScene()
{
    self.view?.presentScene(parentScene!)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to keep a reference to your old scene around, and then when you want to move back to it, simply call

```
skView.presentScene(firstScene)
```

on your SKView instance.

There are several ways to keep a reference to your class around. You could use a [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), or simply a class with a [class type property](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-XID_338) to store the reference and access it from anywhere.

Comment: And i how i do that and in what Method? Thanks

Comment: How did you transfer to your second scene?

Comment: From MyScene , in touchBegan Method i create a new var scene2 = SecondScene( size : self.size ) and then i call self.view.presentScene(scene2)

Comment: You will have to somehow bring a reference to your first scene over into your second scene and then call `self.view.presentScene(scene1)` inside Scene Two. The only other place you could acces the view from would be the ViewController.

Comment: And how can i do that ? From 3 days i try to find how :(( . Thanks

Comment: You can store it globally with a singleton or class type property (links edited into my answer) and then just use it inside scene two.